# How can I run a script, and then emulate ^V with Auto Hot Key (AHK)?

Tags: windows-7, keyboard-shortcuts, autohotkey

I have a script (batch file) to store some inside clipboard, and I need to automatize running and pasting action with auto hot key.

I tried the following code, but the code doesn't work with cmd.exe. I expect a function something like 'Paste clipboard'.

```
+F2::
Run "SCRIPT.bat"
Send {Control down}V{Control up}
Return
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a Command Prompt, Ctrl+V doesn't paste the clipboard.

One way you can paste the clipboard in a Command Prompt is Alt+Space, E, P. So you might try

```
Send !{Space}ep
```

To paste to other Windows programs as well, you can check if the current window is a Command Prompt or not as follows

```
IfWinActive, ahk_class ConsoleWindowClass
{
  Send !{Space}ep
}
Else
{
  Send ^v
}
```

Comment: It works fine with command line, but it doesn't work with other app.

Comment: @prosseek I added a way to check if the current window is a Command Prompt to my answer.