# How to run python script in AHK?

Tags: autohotkey

I have a python script `copytimeinbuffer.py`, and I need to run this with `shift-f1` key.
I used his script.

```
+F1::
Run "c:\bin\python27\python e:/copytimeinbuffer.py"
Send !{Space}ep
Return
```

However, I got this error message.

[image]

What's wrong with the script?

Comment: Somewhat unrelated note: Instead of sending !{Space}ep, you could use [win32clipboard](https://gist.github.com/1219671) to read the clipboard contents.

Comment: @grawity : I did that to emulate '^V' as is answered in http://superuser.com/questions/196631/how-can-i-run-a-script-and-then-emulate-v-with-auto-hot-key-ahk - it doesn't work though.

Comment: I know what !{Space}ep does. I also know that there are *better* ways to do the same thing than sending keypresses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try removing the quotes from your `Run` argument. It could be that AHK is attempting to run a file named `python e:/copytimeinbuffer.py`, instead of just `python`. (The path to your `.py` file is a *separate* argument, and should not need to be quoted.)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. BTW, could you hint me why the print string in python isn't shown in the console? I asked about it in another post - http://superuser.com/questions/336509/debugging-ahk-auto-hot-key-how-can-i-print-out-debug-string-in-python-script

Comment: if there is anyone who have understood what grawity is hinting at please tell, what is the actuall code that will make an interpreter run a .py file

Comment: @user2673238 py -i file

Answer (score 0):

One thing what I found in running python script is that I needed to insert `Sleep 100` before running the other AHK script.