# How to debug AHK, like printing out debug string to console?

Tags: keyboard, autohotkey

I wanted to debug AHK code that calls python script and batch file. I inserted "print SOMETHING" in the python script, but it doesn't seem that the result is shown to the console.

Is there a special trick to print out the debugging message?

When debugging AHK, what people normally use?

Comment: How you run the file

Answer (score 1):

In AHK, you can use [`MsgBox`](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/MsgBox.htm) in the middle of the script, or using [`FileAppend`](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/FileAppend.htm) in order to write into the file.

Otherwise can use [SciTE4AutoHotkey](http://fincs.ahk4.net/scite4ahk/), a lightweight and easy to use SciTE-based AutoHotkey script editor. It can provide interactive debugging.

See also: [Debugging Clients](https://autohotkey.com/docs/AHKL_DBGPClients.htm).

Answer (score 1):

A simple logging function for AutoHotkey v2:

```
; file log
flog(params*){
  logfile := "j:\d\AutoHotkeyLog.log"
  ts := FormatTime(, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.") substr(A_TickCount,-3)
  ; s := A_TickCount
  ; ts := substr(s,-6,3) "." substr(s,-3)
  for ,param in params
    message .= param . " "
  FileAppend ts " " message "`n", logfile
}

eg: flog "The value of i is " i
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this page - http://www.autohotkey.com/forum/topic64248.html

I just put the code `DebugMessage("")` in front of code, and it seems to print the results on the console.

Comment: which results that prints